What happened to my croissant dough when I left it in the fridge overnight?
I made some croissants yesterday. I proved and baked some of them immediately after shaping, and put the rest in the fridge overnight to bake in the morning.
The first batch came out pretty well, by my standards at least!


But the overnight batch didn't seem to prove so well. The dough seemed pockmarked on the surface and didn't hold a nice round shape as it rose. The end result was slightly flatter croissants with a less aerated crumb:



What happened to the dough?
Some information that may or may not be relevant:

I misted the lid of the proving container with water before putting it in the fridge, to keep the dough from drying out.
The dough rose a fair bit in the fridge before lamination as I couldn’t cook it down fast enough
The proved overnight croissants look kind of “soggy” in the photos, while the others look drier. Could this be because I made the proving environment too humid?


Did you cover the croissant dough in the fridge with anything? Refrigerators are usually very dry environments, and the outer layer looks like dried out dough to me.

@Plutian Funny you should say that, I actually thought I’d anything it looked too damp. Yes, I proved then in a container with a lid, which I sprayed lightly with water before putting it on the box. I’m now wondering whether this maybe made the environment too humid.

Does your choon gum lose its flavor on the bedpost overnight?   :-)

I think this was simply over-proofing. By the time the croissants got cold enough to halt fermentation, the dough had been stretched out by CO2 production and then collapsed a bit as the gas bubbles escaped. So you baked looser, less elastic dough the second time around.

The overnight batch went in the fridge straight after shaping, before they'd had a chance to rise. So there shouldn't have been any significant fermentation until the morning, right?

Either way, they were more-or-less the same size when they came out of the fridge, except that the surface looked rougher than when they'd gone in (which then developed into the pockmarks you can see in the photos).

@WillVousden Sneftel is correct. Your dough was overproofed, and that's exactly what's expected to happen under the circumstances. I would be very surprised if I put properly proofed dough into the fridge for a night and it didn't come out overproofed! And all the symptoms you describe are classic overproofing. The unusual thing is that you did it with already-shaped dough - had you tried to work the dough after coming out of the fridge, you'd have noticed how different it is. Anyway, the solution is very simple: just proof until properly proofed, and not longer.

@rumtscho I'm a bit confused now. Most recipes I've read about call for the shaped croissants to be left in the fridge overnight and proofed/baked in the morning, and indeed that's the only way for me to bake them at a reasonable time in the morning as I'm not prepared to get up at 5am to laminate and shape them! When you talk about putting "properly proofed dough into the fridge", what do you mean? These croissants went into the fridge within 5-10 minutes of the final roll/shaping and had not proofed by this point.

That said, the fridge was set to 7°C in this case – could that have been warm enough to allow them to proof slightly overnight, and mess up the final proofing on the counter?

@WillVousden recipes which expect you to proof the croissants for a full night in the fridge will use a different amount of yeast than recipes which are meant to be baked after proofing for an hour of two at room temperature. If you used a recipe which was meant for an overnight proof, then your temperature or duration was more than the recipe writer intended (and small deviations can have large differences, because proofing is based on exponential growth). As for the confusion, I might have misunderstood you - I thought that you proofed your dough at room temperature, then baked (cont.)

(cont.) one batch, and put the other batch in the fridge. I didn't realize that you had put one batch in the fridge before proofing and baking the other. Anyway, whatever the order of doing it, your croissants from the second batch do show signs of overproofing, and a night in the fridge is a common way for that to happen.

Assuming that you hit a comparable proofing stage (as per your description of the volume, although I would agree with Sneftel, that they may have been a bit over the point), there are two elements that can be different when comparing a direct bake vs. overnight proofing:

A longer rest time will give the gluten time to relax. This reduces the overall tension. Yes, the rise counteracts this to a degree, but at least some of the tautness will be lost after a few hours.
The cold dough is prone to condensation when taken out of the fridge and left out on the counter. This condensation can show as spots or pockmarks on the surface. It’s not related to quality, it’s purely a cosmetic issue. Misting in the oven can have the same effect, if the dough goes into the oven cold.


Thanks, that’s interesting. Regarding the gluten relaxing, what effect does this actually have in practice?
